Use a signature file .asc to verfiy a binary with gpg
I have already asked an LLM so I would appreciate it if I can get a human to answer me.
I imported what I believe to be the correct public keys: runc.keyring for the runc.amd64 binaries (the release I am looking at can be found here
As a result I see the following when I type gpg --list-keys:
/home/emmanuel/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
---------------------------------
pub   ed25519 2019-06-21 [C]
      C9C370B246B09F6DBCFC744C34401015D1D2D386
uid           [ unknown] Aleksa Sarai <cyphar@cyphar.com>
sub   ed25519 2022-09-30 [S] [expires: 2030-03-25]
sub   cv25519 2022-09-30 [E] [expires: 2030-03-25]
sub   ed25519 2022-09-30 [A] [expires: 2030-03-25]

pub   rsa4096 2016-06-21 [SC] [expires: 2031-06-18]
      5F36C6C61B5460124A75F5A69E18AA267DDB8DB4
uid           [ unknown] Aleksa Sarai <asarai@suse.com>
uid           [ unknown] Aleksa Sarai <asarai@suse.de>
sub   rsa4096 2016-06-21 [E] [expires: 2031-06-18]

pub   rsa3072 2019-07-25 [SC] [expires: 2025-07-27]
      C020EA876CE4E06C7AB95AEF49524C6F9F638F1A
uid           [ unknown] Akihiro Suda <akihiro.suda.cz@hco.ntt.co.jp>
uid           [ unknown] Akihiro Suda <suda.kyoto@gmail.com>
sub   rsa3072 2019-07-25 [E] [expires: 2025-07-27]


Based on my research, I tried many things, but mostly it is alongside the lines of the following:
gpg --keyring pubring.kbx --default-key C9C370B246B09F6DBCFC744C34401015D1D2D386 --verify runc.amd64.asc runc.amd64

However, regardless of what I tried, I was not able to force gpg to use the public key which I suspect to have been used in signing this binary (the one with the keyid C9C370B246B09F6DBCFC744C34401015D1D2D386), instead, the tool seems to be attempting to use another key as shown here:
gpg: keyblock resource '/home/emmanuel/.gnupg/pubring.kbx': File exists
gpg: Signature made Mon 07 Oct 2024 11:28:24 PM CEST
gpg:                using RSA key C2428CD75720FACDCF76B6EA17DE5ECB75A1100E
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key

Admittedly, I find these tools to be very confusing and I understand little of how they work. Hence, if you feel kind enough to supplement your answer with an explanation on what to read in order to educate myself on this stuff, I would greatly appreciate it!
gpg: Good signature from "Aleksa Sarai <cyphar@cyphar.com>"

GnuPG is correct, If you would run gpg --list-packets runc.amd64.asc you'll see the following:
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 17DE5ECB75A1100E
    version 4, created 1728336504, md5len 0, sigclass 0x00
    digest algo 8, begin of digest 03 19
    hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 C2428CD75720FACDCF76B6EA17DE5ECB75A1100E)
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2024-10-07)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 17DE5ECB75A1100E)
    data: [2047 bits]

I.e. this detached signature produced by exactly the RSA key you mentioned.
Probably something went wrong during signing and should be communicated to the repository owners.
